# /casper/vmlinuz:f ile not found

Tags: system-installation, system

I get this error `/capser/vmlinuz: file not found` when I try to install Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS  using the iso file on my Windows 7 PC.

Can someone help with a solution to this issue.

Comment: above error shown while booting from the ubuntu live disk.Am i correct?

Comment: Hi, Assuming that by live disk you mean, a DVD containing iso file, Yes, I get it while booting.

Comment: check the `md5sum` of the download iso file and also try to create bootable Ubuntu live disk through unetbootin software.

Comment: hi, I checked he md5sum of the file and it is correct. I want to install Ubuntu permanently and not run it just once. Will that be possible using liveCD?

Comment: yes it's possible.